# How can i use an external accelerometer on stm32f429 discovery board. I want to display the analog values through uart

Tags: keil, stm32f4discovery

How can I use an external accelerometer to sense its values and display its analog values itself to display through uart on stm32f429 discovery board?

I have tried using 3 pins as my gpio input. Stuck after that.

```
int main(void)
{

 HAL_Init();

 SystemClock_Config();

 MX_GPIO_Init();
 MX_USART1_UART_Init();


 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

 __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;

 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

 __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_6;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;

 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

 while (1)
 {  

 }
}
```

Comment: On the STM32F429 Discovery, PA2 is connected to the onboard motion sensor (not exactly an accelerometer), PA4 and PA6 are connected to the TFT display. So, what kind of hardware do you have, and how is it connected?

Comment: its stm32f429 board

Comment: I am using an adxl345 as my accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by consulting with the [adxl345 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Accelerometer/ADXL345.pdf). Notable in there is that the adxl345 is a device that talks over I2C or SPI. In your code, you will need to enable the correct peripheral and communicate with the device in that way. The code you posted does none of this, rather it just enables a few GPIO pins. In order to do what you are asking, you will need code to do the following:

1. Initialize and enable the UART interface.
2. [Initialize and enable the I2C (or SPI) interface.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312998/how-to-properly-initialize-i2c-stm32)
3. Capture data from the device over the I2C (or SPI) interface.
4. Write your captured data over a UART.

For steps 1 & 4, there are plenty of examples out there for initializing and writing data over a UART for this board.